# Aggregation in Prolog

Tags: prolog, aggregation, swi-prolog

i try to understand, how the aggregation in swi-Prolog works.

Therefore i use the table works_on with the attributs Employee_Id, Projectnumber, Hours.

In Prolog a fact of this table would look like works_on(1,2,3).

Now i want to find out, how many hours has been worked on each project. Therefore i imported
the library aggregate with the command: use_module(library(aggregate)).

Now i can use the aggregate/3 function, but i don't understnad how this function works...
I guess that the first argument of the function are the variables, the second the 
query to bind these variables and the third should be the variable in which the 
result is stored.

So my guess for the query is aggregate( (X,sum(Y)) , (works_on(_,X,Y), Result ). 
But this query throws an error and i don't understand the documentation...

I hope someone can tell me the right query with an explanation, how aggregate/3 works.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: My guess for the query should be aggregate( (X,sum(Y)) , works_on(_,X,Y), Result ).  - in the post above is a "(" too much

Comment: Please post the full code, and provide some sample data such that it is an MWE (minimal working example)

Comment: What did you get when you entered `aggregate( (X,sum(Y)) , works_on(_,X,Y), Result )`?

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen a reasonable explanation of `aggregate/3` on the internet. My best guess is that the predicates you use as the first argument are somehow special. They do not behave as normal predicates nor functions.

That said, here is an example to solve your question:

```pl
work_on("roy", "drink_coffee", 3).
work_on("roy", "watch_video", 2).
work_on("max", "drink_coffee", 3).
work_on("max", "watch_video", 2).

bagof([Project,Total],
      aggregate(sum(Hour), Name^work_on(Name,Project,Hour), Total),
      Hours_Per_Project).

% [["drink_coffee", 6], ["watch_video", 4]].
```